# Thickbock data validation in googlespreadsheet how to return multiple values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I created a googlespreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K5oc6-XcgMTUSCICr9GguxHWkrm1UuMhnzXu9Rn3ngY/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to return values from all the "checked" thickboxes in a single row like the image below.

Can I do this using a formula?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:C=TRUE, 
 {A1&",", B1&",", C1}, )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While it can be done in an arrayformula for the whole column, you might try this simple JOIN() formula, dragged down the column.  Starting in D2:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(A$1:C$1,A2:C2)))
```